# Send properties in child lit-element

Tags: javascript, web, lit-element

I'm trying to build a web application using lit-element. I have main class named App and secondary class - popup which has properties such as time and text.

In App I have:

```
class App extends LitElement {
    ...
    render() {
        return html`
            <myapp-popup .time="5000" .text="this is a test"></myapp-popup>
            ...
        `;
    }
    ...
}
customElement.define('my-app', App);
```

In Popup:

```
class Popup extends LitElement {
    ...
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.display = 'show';
        setTimeout(() => this.display = 'hide', this.time);
    }
    render() {
        return html`
            <span class="pop-up ${this.display}>${this.text}</span>
        `;
    }
}
customElement.define('myapp-popup', Popup);
```

The problem is that in the `constructor` of `Popup` variable `time` is still undefined even though I passed it as a property in `App.render()`.

How to correctly pass something into child lit-element so it will be available in child's constructor?

Comment: You have passed ``.time`` not ``time``. Remove the dot before ``time``.

Comment: It's still undefined.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to accomplish? https://stackblitz.com/edit/popup-demo

Comment: @Thad, thanks, that's what I've needed for this pop-up.

Comment: @Demiler I recommend you check out https://open-wc.org/ for examples and tooling.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do `<myapp-popup .time=${5000} text=${"this is a test"}></myapp-popup>`. Note the use of `.` for before the attribute.

In an ideal world you'll define the property type on the element itself and it'll parse it as such: `Number`, `String`, `Array`, etc. Doc [here](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties)

Also, you may want to consider using `connectedCallback` lifecycle method instead of the constructor (?)